# How do I remove the /view in the url of my view page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, web, url-rewriting

I developed my site [jobgurus.com.ng](http://www.jobgurus.com.ng) with codeigniter. For SEO purpose, How do I change the view page url form www.jobgurus.com.ng/jobs/view/system-support to www.jobgurus.com.ng/jobs/system-support

I want to remove the /view in the url.

Any help will appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Only that one page? It appears you may already have an `.htaccess` file. You should post it here, so that we don't mess up your current routing.

Comment: Have you read/tried anything from the [URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) docs?

Comment: Got the brackets and parenthesis reversed @scrappedcola

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following code in your **`.htaccess`** file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^view/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Explanation of the flags used:

```
L  -> Last
NC -> No case comparison
R  -> Redirection
```

**Note:** The default code for redirection is 302. You can change it to 301 of you want that by setting: **`[L,NC,R=301]`**.

Answer (score 0):

If `job` is your controller name and `view` is your method, You can use route of CI.
Add below line in file `application/config/routes.php`

```
 $route['job/(:any)'] = 'job/view/$1';
```

you can list similarly all possible links there.